# What is the action for custom accessory view button - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This seems to have been asked a few times in swift and objc, but I can't see a correct answer for swift so hopefully someone can help me this time. I have created a custom accessory view button, but need the correct button action: as "accessoryButtonTapped" is an unrecognised selector.

What is the selector needed to call the tableViewCellDelegate method willSelectRowAtIndexPath?

The code I have is:

```
let cellAudioButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
cellAudioButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
cellAudioButton.addTarget(self, action: "accessoryButtonTapped", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) //INCORRECT ACTION:
cellAudioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "blueSpeaker.png"), forState: .Normal)
cellAudioButton.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
cell.accessoryView = cellAudioButton as UIView
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you need to call `willSelectRowAtIndexPath`? You have done everything right and to solve your `unrecognized selector` error just make a function that will be called when you tap on the `cell.accessoryView`. In your case:

```
func accessoryButtonTapped(){
    print("Tapped")
}
```

**Update**
If you want to get the indexPath you could just

Add a tag to your `cellAudioButton`:

```
cellAudioButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

In your `addTarget` add a `:` to pass a parameter

And in your function

```
func accessoryButtonTapped(sender : AnyObject){
        print(sender.tag)
        print("Tapped")
    }
```

So the whole code:

```
let cellAudioButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        cellAudioButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
        cellAudioButton.addTarget(self, action: "accessoryButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        cellAudioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "blueSpeaker.png"), forState: .Normal)
        cellAudioButton.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        cellAudioButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.accessoryView = cellAudioButton as UIView

func accessoryButtonTapped(sender : AnyObject){
        print(sender.tag)
        print("Tapped")
    }
```

Comment: because i need the indexPath.

Comment: And assuming there are many sections, how do I condense the full IndexPath in the tag?

Comment: @FabrizioBartolomucci, you will get the section from `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: @FabrizioBartolomucci You can create a subclass of UIButton with a variable that holds an `indexPath` object. Then in the action function, you can cast the `sender` to your custom UIButton, and access the `indexPath` that way.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3.1** Updated Solution of **Rashwan**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
       //add button as accessory view
        let cellAudioButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        cellAudioButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        cellAudioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.accessoryButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cellAudioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "closeRed"), for: .normal)
        cellAudioButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        cellAudioButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.accessoryView = cellAudioButton as UIView

        return cell
    }
func accessoryButtonTapped(sender : UIButton){
        print(sender.tag)
        print("Tapped")
    }
```

**Note:**

Here **ViewController** is the name of **Class** like **LoginViewController**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `UITableViewDelegate`?

```
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath)
```

To clarify that, yet it is possible. You can have custom UI elements act as accessory button.

Here is an example – assuming you're using Interface Builder. Add a `UISwitch` to the custom cell. Now right-click drag-n-drop from the `UITableViewCell` to the `UISwitch`. Select `accessoryView` as the Outlet connection. Done.

Every time you press the switch button the delegate method will be fired. This should also work for other action elements, e.g., `UIButton`s. And that is exactly the use case OP asked for.

Comment: He has a custom cell UITableViewCell with logic inside. Your proposition leads to moving this action logic from a custom UITableViewCell to UITableViewDelegate or UIViewController.